# filter data by maximum group sample size with duplicate maximum values

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the `iris` data set with the addition of a `Year` column as created below, I want to group by `Species` and `Year` to select the `Year` with the maximum number of observations for each `species`.

```
iris$Year <- c(rep(c("2007", "2008"), each = 25),
               rep(c("2007", "2008"), times = c(10, 40)),
               rep(c("2007", "2008"), times = c(40, 10)))
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Year
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2007
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 2007
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 2007
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 2007
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2007
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2007
```

As seen in the summary table below, both `2007` and `2008` have 25 observations (rows) for `setosa`. When there are ties in the number of observations, I want to select the minimum `Year`.

In short, I am trying to select only setosa 2007, versicolor 2008, and virginica 2007 from the reproducible data set above, prefably using `dplyr`

**EDIT**Note, rather than create a summary table, I want to select the respective species-year combinations from the `iris` data created above. In other words, I want to subset `iris` to include only setosa 2007, versicolor 2008, and virginica 2007 (i.e. the minimum year with the max number of observations). Sorry for the confusion.  **End Edit**

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species, Year) %>%
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  as.data.frame()

     Species Year  N
1     setosa 2007 25
2     setosa 2008 25
3 versicolor 2007 10
4 versicolor 2008 40
5  virginica 2007 40
6  virginica 2008 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are halfway there. You need to group by just Species, sort according to what you want to keep, and take the top row from each species.

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species, Year) %>%
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  arrange(desc(N), Year) %>%
  slice(1)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Groups:   Species [3]
#      Species  Year     N
#       <fctr> <chr> <int>
# 1     setosa  2007    25
# 2 versicolor  2008    40
# 3  virginica  2007    40
```

If you wanted to keep the ties rather than break them, you could replace the `arrange %>% slice` with `filter(N == max(N))`.

Comment: Or `filter(row_number() == 1)` :-)

Comment: Or: `iris %>% count(Species, Year) %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% distinct(Species, .keep_all = TRUE)` or maybe more readably `iris %>% count(Species, Year) %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice(which.max(n))`

Comment: @Frank, I prefer being explicit about my tie-breakers than relying on inexplicit sorting behavior.

Comment: @Gregor, I added clarity to better describe the desired outcome, which is a subset of `iris` rather than a subset of the summary table.

Comment: @B.Davis Take my answer and add `%>% inner_join(iris)` at the end to get your desired output.